# Waiting time of SUMO

Tags: sumo

I am using sumo for traffic signal control, and want to optimize the phase to reduce some objectives. During the process, I use the traci module as an output of states in traffic junction. The confusing part is traci.lane.getWaitingTime.

I don't know how the waiting time is calculated and also after I use two detectors as an output to observe, I think it is too large.

Can someone explain how the waiting time is calculated in SUMO?

Answer (score 0):

The waiting time essentially counts the number of seconds a vehicle has a speed of less than 0.1 m/s. In the case of traci.lane this means it is the number of (nearly) standing vehicles multiplied with the time step length (since traci.lane returns the values for the last step).